# switch to another view controller while rotating device

Tags: swift, view, controller, switch-statement

Is it possible to switch to another view controller only by turning the device to left/right?

I would try it with:
//LandscapeTabView

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {

    if UIDevice.current.orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft || UIDevice.current.orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.landscapeRight {  

    } 
    else {

    }
```

But don't know what to fill in that function?
Thanks for helping a rookie!

Answer (score 0):

First: you can subscribe to system notification about device rotating like this

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.orientationChanged), name: NSNotification.Name.UIDeviceOrientationDidChange, object: nil)
```

Then make function

```
func orientationChanged() {}
```

For correct state determining I recommend using this method

```
UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation == .portrait
```

If its true - portrait, false - landscape

So, depended on state, for example, you can **push** some vc on landscape and **pop** it when device is turned back.
 For pushing you can easily create an instance of your ViewController like that

```
let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("here_is_vc_id") as! YourViewController
```

And for pop:

```
_ = navigationController.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

Notice: VC you're instantiating must be store at one (and main) storyboard. Also you need to set up an is (where the string "here_is_vc_id" goes) in Identity Inspector in "Storyboard ID" field.

Here you go :)

Answer (score 0):

**Try my little effort-**

```
func rotated()
    {
        if(UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation))
        {
            print("landscapeMode")
            let nextView = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("HomeWorkViewController") as! HomeWorkViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextView, animated: true)

        }

        if(UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation))
        {
            print("PortraitMode")
            //As you like
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The approaches suggested are valid but the recommended way to react to this kind of changes is using `UIContentContainer` protocol (iOS8+).

Then you can add a child view controller to your controller and control how it should animate. You can use this as a reference: [Implementing a Container View Controller](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html).

```
override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransitionToSize(size, withTransitionCoordinator: coordinator)

    let isPortrait = size == UIScreen.mainScreen().fixedCoordinateSpace.bounds.size

    // Add a child view controller if landscape, remove it if portrait...
}
```